# Different rounding rule based on number of digits before the decimal

Tags: r, rounding, digits

Say we have the following numerical vector:

```
y=c(0.111,1.11,11.1,111.1)
```

I would like it to be rounded as follows:

```
0.11,1.11,11.1,111
```

This rule is simple: I want three digits in total! But if the number is large (e.g. 1111 or 11111) then keep all digits, but without any decimals.

Surely, there has to be a simpler solution?:

```
lapply(y,function(x){
  ifelse(nchar(as.integer(x))<1,round(x,digits=3),
         ifelse(nchar(as.integer(x))==1,round(x,digits=2),
                ifelse(nchar(as.integer(x))==2,round(x,digits=1),
                       ifelse(nchar(as.integer(x))>2,round(x,digits=0)
                       ))))
}
)
```

Comment: you could use multiple `ifelse` statements, or the `dplyr::case_when` and write specific rules?

Comment: Yeah, but how? How to count the number of digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear whether the question is about pretty printing (result is *character*) or rounding (result is *numeric*).

If the question is about conversion to character for pretty printing, the `sprintf()` function can be used.

The `sprintf()` function understands the conversion specifier `g` where the number of *significant digits* can be specified. However, it does not cover the whole range of values. Therefore, different conversion specifiers have to be used depending on the size of `y`:

```
y <- c(0.0111, 0.111, 1.11, 11.1, 111.1, 1111, 11111)
sprintf(c("%3.2f", "%3.3g", "%3.0f")[cut(y, c(0, 1, 1000, Inf))], y)
```

> ```
> [1] "0.01"  "0.11"  "1.11"  "11.1"  "111"   "1111"  "11111"
> ```

If the question is about rounding numeric values:

```
round(y, c(2, 1, 0)[cut(y, c(0, 10, 100, Inf))])
```

> ```
> [1]     0.01     0.11     1.11    11.10   111.00  1111.00 11111.00
> ```

#### Explanation

```
c("%3.2f", "%3.3g", "%3.0f")[cut(y, c(0, 1, 1000, Inf))]
```

is a replacement for nested `ifelse()` in order to pick the right conversion specifier for each `y`:

> ```
> [1] "%3.2f" "%3.2f" "%3.3g" "%3.3g" "%3.3g" "%3.0f" "%3.0f"
> ```

`cut()` converts from numeric to factor. It divides the range of `y` into intervals and codes the values in `y` according to which interval they fall. The leftmost interval corresponds to level one, the next leftmost to level two and so on. (from `help("cut")`).

Then, the level number is used to subset the vector of conversion specifiers to pick the appropriate specifier according to the value of `y`.

While writing the explanation, there is a slightly different approach. Instead of using the level numbers to subset the vector of conversion specifiers, we can use the labels of the levels directly:

```
sprintf(as.character(cut(y, c(0, 1, 1000, Inf), labels = c("%3.2f", "%3.3g", "%3.0f"))), y)
```

> ```
> [1] "0.01"  "0.11"  "1.11"  "11.1"  "111"   "1111"  "11111"
> ```

Comment: I forgot to point out this is for "pretty printing", so character is fine. This one is the only one that does exactly what I was looking for. Could you please explain whats going on?

Comment: @user2862862, I have added an explanation (and a code variant). Is the explanation helpful, or do you miss a point?

Answer (score 7):

Just use `signif`:

```
y <- c(0.111,1.11,11.1,111.1,1111)
signif(y, pmax(3,trunc(log10(y)+1)))
#[1]    0.111    1.110   11.100  111.000 1111.000
```

The `pmax(...)` part accounts for the case in which the number has 4 or more digits before the decimal (`log10` is just a way to count those digits).

Answer (score 3):

Does this work?

```
y <- c(0.111,1.11,11.1,111.1,1111,11111)
(ry <- gsub("0+$","",round(y*100)/100))
## [1] "0.11"  "1.11"  "11.1"  "111.1" "1111"  "11111"
as.numeric(ry)
## [1]     0.11     1.11    11.10   111.10  1111.00 11111.00
```

I don't generally like solutions that convert to character, but it seems to do what you want ... (note that this *rounds* as you want, but the printing of the numeric values re-includes the zero values: `cat(ry,"\n")` will print the numbers out as-is)

Comment: Thats a nice solution! Oh, I must have forgotten about the character/numeric issue. And it is for "pretty printing", so character is fine. Thanks!